# KDB: user-defined aggregation function on tables

Tags: aggregate, kdb

Consider a simple user-defined aggregation function `MySum:{sum x}`, and consider the table

```
data:([]y:1 8 27 64 125;x1:1 2 3 4 5;x2:1 4 9 16 25).
```

Why does the following not work?

```
select MySum{x}x2 from data
`rank
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use :

```
 q)select enlist MySum x2 from data
```

**Why 'select Mysum x2 from data' doesn't work?**

From KDB WIKI:  "The following functions receive special treatment within select

count,first,last,sum,prd,min,max,med,avg,wsum,wavg,var,dev,cov,cor "

For Details, read:
http://code.kx.com/q/ref/qsql/#select

Section:    Special functions within select